# Etiquette and/or optimal way to write to a file

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

I am currently questioning a snippet of code, in regards to its effectivity and resource drain. The following is a global logging utility method that will be compiled into a DLL. The method may be accessed concurrently.

```
private static void Log(string logType,
                        string severity,
                        object sender,
                        string format,
                        params object[] args)
    {
        if (Logger._logLock.WaitOne(250))
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Logger._activityLogPath, true))
                {
                    if (logType != "RAW")
                    {
                        sw.Write("{0} {1} {2} ",
                            DateTime.Now,
                            logType,
                            severity);
                    }

                    sw.WriteLine(format, args);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Logger._logLock.ReleaseMutex();
            }
        }
    }
```

What is bothering me is the "using" block that is going to be creating a stream from the same file, each and every time something is logged (multi-calls per second). I am aware of file caching so I'm not entirely sure that reinstalling the stream is too big of an issue (unnecessary stream-buffer initialization however?). I was toying with the idea of adding the StreamWriter as a variable in the Logger class, but I also want to make sure that the writer is properly closed or flushed if the unit is improperly hard-shutdown. The end-users are known to just shut the unit off. I'm trying to find the balance between safety and speed and was just hoping for a bit of insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Yes, creating a stream every time is not really efficient. You might consider, for example, that you collect messages in some sort of collection and write/append this collection in a fixed interval, may be from another thread, to a file... That way you wont need to wait 250ms since the message could be append to the collection and the thread will consume the content of the collection. You should also keep the stream open - the way you do it might fail if some other application locks the file... If you flush after writing a hard-shutdown should not effect the content of the log-file.

b) There are numerous logging frameworks that are well tested, flexible and have awesome performance... Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and confirmation. I will start looking for some of the pre-made frameworks you mentioned. I just wanted to make sure I was not missing something critical for why the code was written the way it was. The original coder was no slouch, and that code just seemed very non-characteristic of him so I though that there must have been a reason he did it the way he did.

Comment: To be clear, if implemented as you suggest, anything that has been logged to the collection, that has not yet been flushed to the file at the time of a hard-shutdown, will be lost. Keep this in mind when determining an appropriate flush interval. Not saying this is bad/good or indifferent (depends on the logging requirements of the system).

Comment: Also keep in mind that Exceptions (if logging them) should be logged and flushed immediately.

Comment: @Kevin Good point. Another reason to use existing logging solutions. Writing you're own might be, depending on the requirements, a good option. But there are many pitfalls you might encounter writing your own. I would recommand using an existing solution, like NLog, for example

Comment: @Kevin I am logging exceptions and in the new implementation I will be sure to route those appropriatly to be flushed asap. Maybe that was the resoning behind the initial reinit: rather than differentiate severity just flush everything and worry less.

Answer (score 0):

> I also want to make sure that the writer is properly closed or flushed if the unit is improperly hard-shutdown.

It won't be properly closed if the user turns the device off while the stream is not flushed, whether you use `using` or not (the critical time span may be shorter with `using` and without manually flushing).

Instead of creating a new `StreamWriter` each time, create it once and flush it after writing. But be aware that you need some kind of hardware (read: buffer battery, UPS) if you want to be 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah, creating it once seems to be what I was going for. I just wanted to make sure i wasnt missing anything critical in regards to the methodology of the using statement. Prior coder worked for MS at one point so I thought there had to be a reason for the reinit. Maybe he just had an off day, or maybe the impact is negligable. Either way, thanks.